# vba loop to check headers and set variable to column letter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small module I created that I want to start at Cell A1 and check from A1 - Z1 for a string. Once the string is found, it sets the `vari` variable to what letter the column is. Code is below that has not been setting the A to Z statement.

```
For y = A To Z
If Range(y & 1) = "Action" Or Range(y & 1) = "Title" Then
  vari = y
End If
Next y
```

I am not sure what I am missing or doing incorrectly (I am very new to VBA) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
For y = 1 To 26
If Cells(1, y) = "Action" Or Cells(1, y) = "Title" Then
  vari = y
End If
Next y
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. I am guessing excel does not know "Column letters" and that is just for human readability then?

Comment: You're welcome. The syntax for `range` is `range("A1")`. Easier to use `cells` in your case.

Comment: Thanks. Greatly appreciated!